# How to use regex for jasmine matchers

Tags: regex, jasmine, protractor, string-matching

I need to verify the text label but it contains dynamic part, so I try to use regex but it doesn't work.

```
expect(aboutPage.userInterfaceText.getText()).toMatch('/- User Interface: v \d+\.\d+\.\d+/');
```

I always get next error:

```
- Expected '- User Interface: v 4.4.63' to match '/- User Interface: v d+.d+.d+/'.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> `- Expected '- User Interface: v 4.4.63' to match '/- User Interface: v d+.d+.d+/'.`

As you can see the slashes at both ends of the pattern are also included into the expression, but your `- User Interface: v 4.4.63` test string does not contain the slashes.

You *should not enclose the regular expression in the single quotes* to make it a [valid regular expression object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
expect(aboutPage.userInterfaceText.getText()).toMatch(/- User Interface: v \d+\.\d+\.\d+/);
```

Works for me on the console:

```
> var s = "- User Interface: v 4.4.63";
> var re = /- User Interface: v \d+\.\d+\.\d+/;
> s.match(re)
["- User Interface: v 4.4.63"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the pattern to string then you can use the match() to check the regex matchers

```
expect(control.errors.pattern.requiredPattern).toString().match('^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\S\./0-9]*$');
```

or like this

```
expect(control.errors.pattern.requiredPattern).toString().match(/^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\S\./0-9]*$/);
```